# (OSX/Cocoa) How to set controller for main window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I've created a new cocoa application using .xib files (not storyboarded, the app has to be backwards compatible with mavericks/mountain lion) and I would like to have a custom windowcontroller for the main window. Is this possible? I can't seem to find a way to connect the window to my desired custom controller. The window has a reference outlet in AppDelegate, however I need a custom NSWindowController for this window as it doesn't open on application launch. The application launches silently as a menu bar app and the main application is launched via button press in the drop down from the menu bar.

Is there a way to link a controller to the window in the interface builder? Or do I have to do something along the lines of :

```
 wc = [[CustomWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Main"];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, open up `Utilities` (the right panel) in Interface Builder, and at the bottom click on the `Object Library` (circle with square in it).
Search for `Object` (blue cube), and drag it into your `Document Outline` (the panel on the left inside of interface builder)
From there, select that object you just created, and change the `Class` in the `Identity Inspector` to be the window controller you want.

Finally you can go into the `Connections Inspector` and connect your `window` to the `window` outlet

Comment: This worked however it does not let me instantiate the window as follows:     mainAppController = [[Testcontroller alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainMenu"];
    [mainAppController showWindow:self];   I get the following error: Failed to connect (delegate) outlet from (Testcontroller) to (AppDelegate): missing setter or instance variable

Comment: is mainAppController a local variable?  Based off of your snippet there, it looks like it.  Try making a property (instance variable) like this: `@property Testcontroller *mainAppController`.  Then reference it w/ self.mainAppController.  Also pass `nil` as the argument to `-showWindow`.  Lastly, make sure that your File's Owner (app delegate) isn't connected to the window anymore.  Click on File's Owner, go to the connections inspector and make sure you remove that connection

Answer (score 3):

> I can't seem to find a way to connect the window to my desired custom
>   controller. The window has a reference outlet in AppDelegate, however
>   I need a custom NSWindowController for this window as it doesn't open
>   on application launch.

Another way:

1)  Delete the window in MainMenu.xib. Delete the window property in AppDelegate.m--because you deleted the window, it is no longer relevant.

2)  File>New>File>Cocoa Class.  Enter a class name, e.g. MainWindowController; select "Subclass of: NSWindowController"; check "Also create .xib file for user interface".

3) Create an outlet in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MainWindowController* windowController;

@end
```

4) Declare an action in AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

-(IBAction)launchWindow:(id)sender;

@end
```

and implement it in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)launchWindow:(id)sender {
    [self setWindowController:[[MainWindowController alloc]
                               initWithWindowNibName:@"MainWindowController"]];

    [[self windowController] showWindow:nil];
}
```

5) In MainMenu.xib, hook up the Menu Item to the launchWindow() action:  control drag from the Menu Item to the AppDelegate object and select launchWindow.

Comment: this doesn't set the window as the `mainWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Create the controller and make it extend from NSWindowController.
In your xib file select the File's Owner and set it to your custom class.
Select your NSWindow and connect it to the File's Owner.

To open the window:

In your .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourWindowController *yourWinController;
```

In your .m:

```
self.yourWinController = [[YourWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"YourWindowController"];
[self.yourWinController showWindow: nil];
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in my case since I'm talking about the "MainMenu.xib" that gets created with the empty application. The current file owner is of type NSApplication. Would setting that too an NSWindowController not cause issues? What you mentioned above is what I've done for .xib files that only contain a window. However the MainMenu.xib contains other objects as well.

Comment: why don't you create a separate xib for your window?

Comment: I could however then I would have to duplicate all the things like the menu that appears in the top left of the menu bar etc. I just need an easy way to launch this main window from a button click somewhere outside of AppDelegate.

Comment: I think you can't get a NSWindowController between the NSApplication (Files owner of the MainMenu.xib) and the nib.